# Dim part of MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview, uilabel

I have a label that overlays on an `MKMapView`. The only problem is, in some parts it is not totally readable, as the map is in satellite imagery. Also, my map view zooms in the whole way, it focuses on a **shop**.

I looked at the new map application for Apple and have found that they dim (put a slightly black shadow) over the map region where the label is around. Therefore the label will be slightly more visible and outstanding.

Here is a picture of what Apple does, look at the label, around it you can see the map is slightly darkened/dimmed:

[image]

Do you have any ideas on how I can add a shadow/dim the map view. Also, a bit of sample code wouldn't hurt, thanks!

Comment: Can you post an image of Apple's version of this?

Comment: Sure.... I will just edit the question

Comment: @EvanMulawski I have posted it

Comment: Will the label be in the corner like the image? Or will it move around?

Comment: It is fixed in the bottom right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use gradient overlay, with transparency and add the `UILabel` into that gradient overlaid `UIView`.

Useful link to get started : http://mrohs.com/2011/overlay-with-gradient-and-transparency

Comment: Let me try this out and get back to you

Comment: If the place is static then it's easier you can just create a png image in photoshop and have label on it :)

Comment: It is not, I am implementing Google Places, the user can select multiple places, so the location is not static, it can change

Comment: @RohanKapur, here we go...this sample project will help you. hopefully https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63115907/GRadientOverlay.zip

Comment: Ahhh, that is EXACTLY what I needed, it is a great image. Thank you